# Closed graph proof and existence of continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I'm working on an exercise in which you need to prove the existence of a certain function, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. A previous assignment had a similar proof that I couldn't figure out either, so I'd like some assistance please!

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces and $T : X \to Y$ a linear map.

(a) I first want to prove that the graph $G(T)$ of $T$ is closed in $X \times Y$ if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $x_n \to 0$ and $(Tx_n)$ converges in $Y$, the $\lim_{n \to \infty} Tx_n = 0$.

Assume now that $X$ and $Y$ are complete and that $T$ is bounded. Let $Z$ be a Banach space for which there exists a continuous injective linear map $J : Z \to Y$. Suppose $T(X) \subset J(Z)$.

(b) I then want to show that there exists a unique linear map $\hat{T}: X \to Z$ such that $T = J \hat{T}$ and prove that $\hat{T}$ is continuous.

What I've done so far:

(a):
$(\Rightarrow)$ If a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converges and sequences $(y_n)$ in $Y$ converges, then the sequence $\{x_n, y_n \}$ converges in $X \times Y$.

If we define $y$ as the limit of $(Tx_n)$, then we know that $(x_n, Tx_n)$ converges in $X \times Y$. Since $(x_n, Tx_n) \in G(T)$, the graph of $T$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $G(T)$ is closed, the limit point $(0, y) \in G(T)$.

Now, since $T$ is a linear map it sends the zero element of $X$ to the zero element of $Y$, we have y = 0.

Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} Tx_n = 0$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ I now need to show that every sequence $(x_n)$ in $G(t)$ with has its limit point $x$ in $G(T)$. This is probably very simple, but I don't see how the statement in the exercise can help me prove this...

(b) As I've said earlier, I'm completely stumped on how to do this...

I thought about just assuming that there is linear map with these properties and trying to show that $T$ is then still linear, but I don't think that that is the correct way to do it...

I know that this is homework and that I've only done a small part of the exercise, so I would be happy with even the smallest hint. This type of question is bound to come up again, so I'd really like to know a general way to solve them.

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: Re a), for a sequence $(x_n, Tx_n)$ in $G(T)$ that converges to $(x,y) \in X\times Y$, consider the sequence $(x_n-x, Tx_n - Tx)$. Re b), Since $J$ is injective, and $T(X) \subset J(Z)$, the map $\hat{T} = J^{-1}\circ T$ is defined. Show that it has the desired properties.

Comment: @DanielFischer 
(a): Ah yes, this implies that $Tx_n = Tx$ so that every limit point is in G(T). Thanks!  
(b): I understand that this is the correct answer, so that $J \circ \hat{T} = J \circ J^{-1} \circ T = I \circ T = T$ and I'll be able to prove that $\hat{T}$ is continuous. What I don't see however is how $J$ can be inverted, how do you know  that $J$ is surjective? Is it because $T(X) \subset J(Z)$, anything T throws at $J^{-1}$ can be handled injectively?

Comment: We have $J^{-1} \colon J(Z) \to Z$, $J^{-1}$ is not necessarily surjective, but the assumption is that $T(X)$ is contained in the domain of $J^{-1}$, so $J^{-1}\circ T$ is defined.

Comment: @DanielFischer Briliant, I see it now. Thank you very much for your help!